# Xamarin, Android: "Failed To Load Ad: 0"

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to monetize my app with Visual Studio (C#).

I am getting this error:

05-16 11:54:11.275 W/Ads     (29382): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
05-16 11:54:11.277 W/Ads     (29382): Failed to load ad: 0

This is my code:

```
AdView adView; 
   adView = FindViewById<AdView>(Resource.Id.adView);
    //Initialize Banner 
    MobileAds.Initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-6088441455894853/5395983723");
    //Load AdRequest (Test enabled!)
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice(AdRequest.DeviceIdEmulator).Build();
    //Start Ad 
    adView.LoadAd(adRequest);
```

And this is my xml:

```
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
      android:id="@+id/adView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      ads:adSize="BANNER"
      ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-6088441455894853/5395983723" >
  </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

When I check the designer, I see my ad displaying right (just without no content clearly). But when I debug my app, I don't see any banner at all.

Unfortunately, there is very little documented about Visual Studio and Ads. Anyone here maybe have an idea?

THANKS :)

Answer (score 1):

this will work only for Test Devices bc you have added the following code (AddTestDevice). once you publish your app.. it will not work

Answer (score 0):

TO EVERYONE:

I CHANGED THE SIZE TO :

ads:adSize="360x100"

AND IT WORKED :)